# ole32.dll causes GPF. How to interpret DebugDiag report?

Tags: exception, com, vb6, debugging, crash

My app ([EasyJob](http://www.easyjob.net)) causes an access violation error on exiting. This only happens on some systems, mostly Vista, but it has happened on some XP boxes. The application is written in VB6.

After finding a system that shows this behavior, I ran DebugDiag  on my process and got this report:

```
Function                            Arg1        Arg2        Arg3
0x04246c81                          726c7fc8    778bf188    0012fea4
ole32!CoDisconnectObject+55         726c7fc8    00000000    00000002
msvbvm60!BASIC_CLASS_Release+10b2d  00000002    013e07cc    727ae518
msvbvm60!TipUnloadProject+df2       013e08dc    013e07cc    727ae470
msvbvm60!EbResetProjectNormal+1a54  00000000    00000000    00000000
```

In easyjobpro__PID__5240__Date__05_18_2009__Time_09_24_01PM__619__Second_Chance_Exception_C0000005.dmp the module C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll has caused an access violation exception (0xC0000005) when trying to write to memory location 0x726c7fc8 on thread 0

OK, so it  looks like it's OLE32.dll that is causing this, but how can I fix it???? O:-)

Is there a way to get a longer stack trace so I can actually see what part of my code started this thing? It seems to be related with some class being unloaded (BASIC_CLASS_Release), but how do I find out which  one?

Anybody knows why this might be happening mostly on Vista?

This stuff is driving me nuts, so ANY help would be GREATLY appreciated. Seriously, I'll buy you a beer no matter where you are. O:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GPF on exit is usually caused by wrong deinitialization sequence. For example, the following could have happened: some code that releases all objects has been called already and now you have a dangling pointer and the code currently executing is trying to release the same object. Since the object is no longer there you get a GPF.

Such situations are usually hard to debug. What you need is a dedicated deinitialization where you would disconnect, finalize, flush, close, etc. all objects that you initialized while running the program. In most cases all you need is to just set the pointet to the object to `Nothing` - built-in resource management will have the object properly deinitialized. You have to execute this code before the whole program termination starts - somewhere like when closing the main window.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that in these cases, it's very often objects that are referenced by VB Forms. If you set the Form's variable to Nothing in the Unload event, and make sure you either call Unload after using the form, or before the application closes, then the GPF goes away.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using John Robbins' [Crashfinder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc188721.aspx) to see whether the hex address (0x04246c81) corresponds to any of your own code. Might give you a clue to which objects are involved. Build the app with debugging info to create a PDB. Then reproduce the error again with the new app (as the PDB info will change the hex address in the exe).

The Crashfinder.exe is in this [self-extracting ZIP](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/6/7/0678184e-905e-4783-9511-d4dca1f492b4/Apr98Bugslayer.exe). Do File-New to create a new project, then Edit-Add Image to load your exe. Then Edit-Find Crash and type in the new hex address. It will tell you the source file and routine corresponding to the hex address (if it is in your own code).